# how to pass self to bottle routing functions?

Tags: python, scope, bottle

I run [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) as part of an environment and cannot understand how to pass variables to its routing functions. The following code runs fine:

```
import bottle

class WebServer():
    message1 = 'hello message1'

    def __init__(self):
        self.message2 = 'hello message2'
        bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)

    @bottle.get('/hello')
    def hello():
        # here I would like to return message1 or message2
        return 'unfortunately only a static message so far'

WebServer()
```

I would like to return `message1` or `message2` (two separate cases) when calling the `/hello` URL. I do not know how to pass `self` to `hello()`, though. How should I do that?

Comment: Don't know bottle, but pass self as a first argument. def hello(self):

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725605/bottle-framework-and-oop-using-method-instead-of-function

Comment: @ndpu: Thanks! using this info and the doc I ended up with a cleaner, working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on [ndpu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1099876/ndpu)'s comment and on [bottle documentation about explicit routing](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#explicit-routing-configuration), I have rewritten the code as

```
import bottle

class WebServer():
    message1 = 'hello message1'

    def __init__(self):
        self.message2 = 'hello message2'
        bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)

    def hello(self):
        # here I would like to return message1 or message2
        # return 'unfortunately only a static message so far'
        # now it works
        return self.message1  # or self.message2

w = WebServer()
bottle.route('/hello', 'GET', w.hello)
```

This ended up being a cleaner way (IMHO) to structure the routing.

Unfortunately this does not seem to work for error routing. I did not find a way to turn the working

```
@bottle.error(404)
def error404(error):
    print('error 404')
    return
```

into something like the above (`bottle.error`...) - [the relevant documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html?highlight=bottle.error#bottle.Bottle.error) mentions that this is a decorator (so I guess it has to stay as it is)